# How to setup Spring Cloud LoadBalancer with RestTemplate?

Tags: spring, load-balancing, spring-cloud

Is there a way to setup the new Spring Cloud LoadBalancer to work with RestTemplate? The only tutorials I find are using Flux and Project Reactor for microservice communications.

Comment: https://www.infoq.com/presentations/netflix-spring-cloud/

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is. You can see [this branch](https://github.com/OlgaMaciaszek/spring-cloud-netflix-demo/tree/non-reactive-new-stack) for a working demo.

Comment: Can you please share the link once again, it seems to be somehow broken...

Comment: @IvanMarkov Sorry for that. Fixed now.